# Getting 500 Internal Server Error while trying to send an email using Mailgun in Heroku , using Rails 7 and mail_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, heroku, mailgun

I was following this tutorial right here https://gist.github.com/stevecondylios/16a53b73f22621e3cde2e17096dbf5ca

Which teaches you how to make a simple contact form with mail_form on Rails 6, I'm using Rails 7 and for the most part, the process is the same, it works well in development, as I've tested several times with MailCatcher and the mails get sent correctly, the only problem I'm stumbling upon is when I try to test the form on production.

The problems comes as a `500 Internal Server Error` from Mailgun, when I submit the form, which has me baffled as I have yet to find a similar issue on the internet, I've cross-referenced several tutorials and issues and I find several other error messages, and a couple with `500 Internal Server Error` but none of the answers to those helped.

I pretty much have the exact same configuration as in the tutorial, but here are my configurations, maybe there is something I missed, note that I have added the real "example@mail.com" to the "Authorized Recipients" section in Mailgun and that I have a custom domain and is working properly with the rest of Heroku, I also have the right ENV vars set on Heroku:

Contact model:

```
class Contact < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      validate: true
  attribute :email,     validate: /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :message
  attribute :nickname,  captcha: true

  # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
  def headers
    {
      :subject => "Contact Form Inquiry",
      :to => "example@mail.com",
      :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
    }
  end
end
```

in production.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :port           => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT'],
  :address        => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER'],
  :user_name      => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN'],
  :password       => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'https://www.example.com/',
  :authentication => :plain,
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Heroku logs:

```
2022-04-28T20:35:32.118071+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/contacts" host=www.pocket-witch.games request_id=b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b fwd="177.249.170.124" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=https
2022-04-28T20:35:32.106145+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-04-28T20:35:32.106072 #4]  INFO -- : [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b] Started POST "/contacts" for 177.249.170.124 at 2022-04-28 20:35:32 +0000
2022-04-28T20:35:32.106961+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-04-28T20:35:32.106912 #4]  INFO -- : [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b] Processing by ContactsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
2022-04-28T20:35:32.107080+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-04-28T20:35:32.107015 #4]  INFO -- : [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b]   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "contact"=>{"name"=>"John", "email"=>"example@mail.com", "message"=>"Example message", "nickname"=>""}, "commit"=>"Send Message"}
2022-04-28T20:35:32.109199+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-04-28T20:35:32.109137 #4]  INFO -- : [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b]   Rendered contact_mailer/contact_mail.html.erb within layouts/mailer (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 8)
2022-04-28T20:35:32.109367+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-04-28T20:35:32.109331 #4]  INFO -- : [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b]   Rendered layout layouts/mailer.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 46)
2022-04-28T20:35:32.109834+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-04-28T20:35:32.109777 #4]  INFO -- : [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b]   Rendered contact_mailer/contact_mail.text.erb within layouts/mailer (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 4)
2022-04-28T20:35:32.109975+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-04-28T20:35:32.109923 #4]  INFO -- : [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b]   Rendered layout layouts/mailer.text.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 41)
2022-04-28T20:35:32.115988+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-04-28T20:35:32.115921 #4]  INFO -- : [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b] Delivered mail 626afa941bd21_45348778b1@b96704a7-29a2-4902-83e1-099673240203.mail (2.8ms)
2022-04-28T20:35:32.116193+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-04-28T20:35:32.116158 #4]  INFO -- : [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (Allocations: 3976)
2022-04-28T20:35:32.116915+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-04-28T20:35:32.116874 #4] FATAL -- : [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b]   
2022-04-28T20:35:32.116916+00:00 app[web.1]: [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b] Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:25):
2022-04-28T20:35:32.116917+00:00 app[web.1]: [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b]   
2022-04-28T20:35:32.116917+00:00 app[web.1]: [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b] app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:11:in `block in create'
2022-04-28T20:35:32.116917+00:00 app[web.1]: [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b] app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

Edit: I've added some of the Heroku ENV variables below, I've made double sure ENV vars like `MAILGUN_DOMAIN`and such match with what I have on my mailgun account.

[image: Heroku ENV variables for Mailgun]

Some additional things that I've noticed is that error seems to stem from whet the `@contact.deliver` action is done, I've tried making my own simple mailer in place of using mail_form, and using `.deliver_now` triggers the same error, using `deliver_later` does not, but the mail never gets sent, so I suspect the error comes from elsewhere.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I've reached an impasse regarding this situation

Comment: I wonder if that has to do with [the use of unescaped quotes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.2.4) in your `from` section. Try removing them and see if that helps.

Comment: I just tried it and no luck, I think I've tried to use different formats for that section with no luck.

Comment: I believe that you're using port 25 to send the email.  it might be that Heroku is blocking that port.  can you try setting `:enable_starttls_auto => true` and `ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT'] = 587`?

Comment: I'm using port 587 according to Heroku ENV variable, I also tried with `:enable_starttls_auto => true` but same thing keeps happening, I keep getting the same error. I updated my question to also have some of the Heroku ENV variables.

Comment: `Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:25` in the log files, looks like those variables aren't being used or respected

Comment: Good catch, I now see what you meant beforehand, I'll look into why the variables aren't being used, thanks.

Comment: I got it, turns out using `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` to setup the mailgun settings on `production.rb` wasn't doing what it should, but using `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` did the trick, very weird behaviour, perhaps I missed something, but it seems that just that was enough to do the trick, thanks again.

Comment: No probs. Can you add an answer so that others can see the whole explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the help of the comments, I was able to notice by the line in the heroku logs:

```
2022-04-28T20:35:32.116916+00:00 app[web.1]: [b1e694c5-cea3-427f-bbdd-aa3cc3a92d6b] Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for 127.0.0.1:25):
```

The port being used was `25` instead of `587` meaning that the block

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :port           => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT'],
  :address        => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER'],
  :user_name      => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN'],
  :password       => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'https://www.example.com/',
  :authentication => :plain,
}
```

Was being ignored, by instead encompassing those option inside a `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings` I was able to resolve the issue.